# how to extract row and column of text in dataframe using regular expression

Tags: r

I want to extract row and column index of a text which contains both 'IDP' & 'SB' in entire dataframe in r.

text pattern looks like following

```
  Col1              Col2
    IDP ENGINE(SB)    IDP ENGINE(PS)
    IDP ENGINE SB01   MAIN ENGINE(SB)
    IDP ENGINE SDV    AUX. ENGINE(SB)
```

My Output will be

```
row column
 1    1
 2    1
```

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to loop through the columns, use `grepl` and then with `which` and `arr.ind = TRUE` get the index

```
which(sapply(df1, function(x)  grepl("(\\bIDP\\b.*\\bSB)|(\\bSB\\bIDP)", x)), arr.ind = TRUE)
#     row col
#[1,]   1   1
#[2,]   2   1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
d = data.frame(
    col1 = c("IDP ENGINE(SB)", "IDP ENGINE SB01", "IDP ENGINE SDV")
    , col2 = c("IDP ENGINE(PS)", "MAIN ENGINE(SB)", "AUX. ENGINE(SB)")
);


d


which(
    apply(d, c(1,2), grepl, pattern="IDP") & apply(d, c(1,2), grepl, pattern="SB")
    , arr.ind = TRUE
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest something like this:

```
which(matrix(grepl(pattern = '(?=.*IDP)(?=.*SB)', as.matrix(df1), perl = TRUE), ncol = NCOL(df1)), arr.ind = TRUE)
```

> ```
>      row col
> [1,]   1   1
> [2,]   2   1
> ```